# Android Programming - Fragments and Listeners

Tags: android, listeners

I am following a tutorial on the internet and I have to make a listener for my buttons. The tutorial I am watching is very different from my code even though the video was posted not even a year ago. The video I am watching has no "fragment" code in it. In my code there is a fragment in my MainActivity.java. What is a fragment? In my mainactivity.java towards the end I get this:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        button1 = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3 = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button3);

        button1.setOnClickListener(listener);
        button2.setOnClickListener(listener);
        button3.setOnClickListener(listener);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

could anyone explain to me what a place holder fragment is? heres my code. I am getting an error here:

```
ERROR: "Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);"
Message: "No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope"
```

.
    private static OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int id = v.getId();

```
        switch(id)
        {
        case R.id.button1:
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            break;
        case R.id.button3:
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

HERES MY FULL CODE ( MainActivity.java ):

```
package com.example.androiddevelopmentonline_part2_1;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private static Button button1, button2, button3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


private static OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();

        switch(id)
        {
        case R.id.button1:
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            break;
        case R.id.button3:
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
};

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        button1 = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3 = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button3);

        button1.setOnClickListener(listener);
        button2.setOnClickListener(listener);
        button3.setOnClickListener(listener);

        return rootView;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the best explanation is in the Developer Docs (here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Here's something from the "QuickView"

> ```
> Fragments decompose application functionality and UI into reusable modules
> Add multiple fragments to a screen to avoid switching activities
> Fragments have their own lifecycle, state, and back stack
> Fragments require API Level 11 or greater
> ```

The way I paraphrase it, is that its a reusable component of the UI with it's own lifecycle. It is used to decompose your UI into (multiple), more self contained, and logical "sections".

In your case, I think your IDE has auto generated the code for you and generated the `PlaceholderFragment`. It is as it says, an autogenerated placeholder. You can get rid of it if you're only working with `Activities` for now. But its best to look up Fragment tutorials later as they are used quite frequently with newer versions of android (Fragments are not necessary, but they're sorta 'better practice', depending on your application architecture).

The reason you're getting an error with:

> ERROR: "Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);"
>
> Message: "No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope"

is actually explained in the message. You've declared your `OnClickListener` into an anonymous, `static`, attribute. Because it is `static`, it cannot access the current instance of the class (it is "not in scope", it has no access to the non-static methods and attributes). To fix it, just remove the `static` keyword:

```
private OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() //... etc
```

For an explanation about the `static` keyword in Java, look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html or [What does the 'static' keyword do in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413898/what-does-the-static-keyword-do-in-a-class)

EDIT (A neater way of implementing OnClickListener)

A better idea would be to put your `OnClickListener` within your `PlaceholderFragment` (since that's where it's used), or have your `PlaceholderFragment` implement `View.OnClickListener` (I prefer this way, less anonymous types, it code formats better, but its a matter of preference). An example (look for the comments):

```
// note, doesn't matter if it is static
// I got rid of the OnClickListener attribute and made PlaceholderFragment implement OnClickListener like so
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener
{
    // No need to provide a constructor. Fragments by default should have an empty constructor. If you want to add data to it, you need to create a "newInstance" method which calls fragment.setArguments (SomeBundleWithValuesInIt)
    @ Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate (R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        button1 = (Button) rootView.findViewById (R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button) rootView.findViewById (R.id.button2);
        button3 = (Button) rootView.findViewById (R.id.button3);

        // I set the OnClickListener to the PlaceholderFragment itself, because it implements OnClickListener (which is an interface), you can use it this way.
        button1.setOnClickListener (this);
        button2.setOnClickListener (this);
        button3.setOnClickListener (this);

        return rootView;
    }

    // OnClickListener.onClick(View) moved here.
    @ Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        int id = v.getId ();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.button1 :
                // getActivity() can be used instead of Context (Activity is one of the subclasses of Context), but only within a Fragment in this case
                Toast.makeText (getActivity (), "toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                break;
            case R.id.button2 :
                break;
            case R.id.button3 :
                break;
            default :
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! but now when i try and add the listener. for example                          button1.setOnClickListener(listener); I get an error saying it can't make a static reference to a non static field. also whenever I delete the fragment and move my code into the on create method. the app fails to launch. thanks alot @AniFichadia

Comment: @user3453481 oh sorry, didn't realize it earlier. It's basically the same thing as your `OnClickListener` with `PlaceholderFragment`, just remove `static`. I'll update my answer because there's a better way of doing it instead of using MainActivity.this, which means putting your `OnClickListener` within `PlaceholderFragment` and using `Fragment.getActivity()` when you use the `Toast` notification

Comment: @user3453481, i should also mention, if you remove static from `PlaceholderFragment`, it means that `PlaceholderFragment` "belongs" to `MainActivity`, so it can access all of its attributes and methods without error